# Vector input for Artificial Neural Network?

Tags: data, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-networks

My problem is fairly complex, so here is a similar, simplified example.

Let's say you wanted to predict the Miles Per Gallon (fuel consumption) of a car, based on the following information: you have the weight of the vehicle in pounds, the number of cylinders in the engine, and a number which corresponds to a type of vehicle (0 = cube car, 1 = standard car, 2 = van, et. cetera), and the amount of rain within the past hour (in gallons).

Say you take all of this information, and compile it into a 4 Dimensional vector, `[Weight, Cylinders, Vehicle Class, Rain]`. Because rain from 4 hours ago is still important, lets say we took multiple of these vectors from the past 5 hours, and feed them into a network, so we have something like this:

```
[Weight 5 hours ago, Cylinders 5 hours ago, Vehicle Class 5 hours ago, Rain 5 hours ago]
[Weight 4 hours ago, Cylinders 4 hours ago, Vehicle Class 4 hours ago, Rain 4 hours ago]
...
[Weight in past hour, Cylinders in past hour, Vehicle Class in past hour, Rain in past hour]
```

Being feed in, resulting in in "current rain amount"

Question: How would one format this problem for use in Artificial Neural Network? Can networks take vectors as inputs? Would it be better to allot each node to a single value (so each vector takes 4 nodes, one for each dimension, resulting in 20 nodes for the set)?

Because of the time changing, I've considered using a HMM/MM however, I am not dealing in exclusively categorical data. This isn't for a class or anything, I'm just learning out of pure interest... Thanks!

Comment: I think your question would be better suited in datascience.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *sliding window* approach (NN is trained to use the last `k` values of a series) is the way to go for a [feed forward neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedforward_neural_network).

Redundant input values should be removed because they can negatively affect the neural network learning ability (another benefit to removing redundant variables is faster training times):

```
[Weight Cylinders VehicleClass Rain5 Rain4 Rain3 Rain2 Rain1]
```

is a first change (consider that the "window size" does have an important effect on the quality of a neural network based forecaster so you should check with different number of `Rain[n]` inputs).

Also instead of using one number for the type of vehicle (0 = cube car, 1 = standard car, 2 = van...) you should use a [1-hot encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469835/one-hot-encoding-for-machine-learning):

```
                  <-- Vehicle Class -->
[Weight Cylinders (0.0 ... 1.0 ... 0.0) Rain5 Rain4 Rain3 Rain2 Rain1]
```

This will work much better, although your feature vector will get much bigger (and, depending on how much data you have, you might suffer from overfitting).

[Recurrent Neural Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network) (check the [Long-Short Term Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short_term_memory) variant) can take into account many instances in the previous time stamps (rain value) and you don't have to define a sliding window.